# Wix bundle installer how to gracefully exit a 'User Cancelled Installation' 0x80070642

Tags: installation, error-handling, wix

I've spent hours and hours looking in to this, reading over everything I can and I still can't find a solution.

I'm using a wix BootstrapperApplicationRef, bundling a couple of installers into one single overall installer.

Suppose whilst going through the first installer I decide that I don't agree with the licence agreement so I decide to cancel.

[image]

I would expect the overall bundle installer to gracefully exit but no, after gracefully exiting from the first installer I am presented with this screen.

[image]

Which makes it seem like something has gone catastrophically wrong when actually this was an intentional exit. How can I make this gracefully exit guys?

I am using wix 3.10 according to the wix project file. This is the code for my bundle with some identifying texts XXXXXX'd out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Release" ?>
  <?define UpgradeCode = "XXXXXX"?>
  <?endif ?>
  <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Debug" ?>
  <?define UpgradeCode = "XXXXXX"?>
  <?endif ?>
  <?define EULAPath = XXXXXX ?>
  <?define BundleName = "XXXXXX" ?>
  <?define VersionNumber = "XXXXXX" ?>
     
  <Bundle Name="$(var.BundleName)" 
          Version="$(var.VersionNumber)"
          Manufacturer="XXXXXX"
          AboutUrl="XXXXXX"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
          IconSourceFile="XXXXXX" >
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="$(var.EULAPath)"
                                              LogoFile="XXXXXX"/>        
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
<?define NetFx472MinRelease = 461808 ?>
<?define NetFx472EulaLink = http://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html ?>

<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx472Redist" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="$(var.NetFx472EulaLink)" Overridable="yes" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx472RedistDetectCondition" Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx472MinRelease)" Overridable="yes" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx472RedistInstallCondition" Value="" Overridable="yes" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx472RedistPackageDirectory" Value="redist\" Overridable="yes" />

<Chain>      
  <ExePackage SourceFile="..\..\ThirdParty\Net_Framework_4_7_2.exe"
    DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx472RedistDetectCondition)"
    InstallCommand="/q /install"
    RepairCommand="/repair"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    Permanent="yes"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="XXXXXX"
        ForcePerMachine="yes"
        Visible="no"  
        DisplayInternalUI="yes"
        Permanent="no"
        Vital="yes" />
  <?if $(var.Configuration) = "Release" ?>
    <ExePackage SourceFile="XXXXXX"
      PerMachine="yes"
      Vital="yes"
      Permanent="no"/>
  <?else?>      
    <ExePackage SourceFile="XXXXXX"        
      PerMachine="yes"
      Vital="yes"
      Permanent="no"/>
  <?endif ?>
</Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <PropertyRef Id="WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED" />
    <Property Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_472_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
    <SetProperty Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_472_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" Value="1" After="AppSearch">
      WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#$(var.NetFx472MinRelease)"
    </SetProperty>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Can you explain what that `ExePackage` after the MsiPackage is doing? v4 might include a new built-in BA for this scenario (show only MSI UI and not bundle UI), but the current design is to only allow one MSI to show UI and it must be the last package in the chain.

Comment: Absolutely, so the the MSI and the EXE are two separate installers for two separate products. The MSI product relies on the EXE product existing for some of its functionality. The reason for the two EXEPackages and the conditional check on the configuration is that there is a UAT version and Release version of that product.

Comment: Are you suggesting that version 4 of wix may be able to handle this kind of installer setup?

Comment: Not exactly. The new built-in BA would only be for the scenario where there are any number of permanent packages (prerequisites) and a single package for the actual product, where that single package shows UI.

`WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` got a lot of new functionality in v4 that should help make writing a bundle UI easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that that is a confusing scenario for your user, but it's not obvious how it could be fixed. Other users may be equally confused that cancelling the MSI causes the main window to completely disappear.

Bundles were designed to have a single UI for everything. `DisplayInternalUI` was implemented as a fallback so that users could still use their MSI UI until they had time to invest in their bundle's UI. The correct way to fix this is to stop letting individual packages show UI.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the response. I will spend some time looking into a single UI. You are exactly right, I am concerned that the current response will confuse my users